# Chrome Firebase Cloud Message - NotRegistered

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am testing the FCM in server with subdomain and https and using the firebase js version of 4.10.1.

The push notification is working fine first time the allow access. I can able to send notification successfully using google (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send).

Then i manually disabled the notification to deny then reload the page. 
Now i tried to send notification using google api and i got error NotRegistered which is correct.

After that i manually enabled the notification to allow then reload the page.
Now i tried to send notification using google api and i got error NotRegistered again.

so what is the issue i have ?

```
https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase.js
var config = {
    apiKey: "XXX",
    authDomain: "XXX",
    databaseURL: "XXX",
    projectId: "XXX",
    storageBucket: "XXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXX"
}
firebase.initializeApp(config);

 var messaging = firebase.messaging();

    messaging.onMessage(function(data) {
        console.log("Message received. ", data);
        var notificationObj = {
            body: data.notification.body,
        };

        if (data.data && data.data['gcm.notification.image']) {
            notificationObj.image = data.data['gcm.notification.image'];
        }

        if (data.notification.icon) {
            notificationObj.icon = data.notification.icon;
        }

        var instance = new Notification(data.notification.title, notificationObj);
        instance.onclick = function(){
            console.log('clicked');
            instance.close();
            window.location.href = data.notification.click_action;
         }
        instance.onshow = function(){
            console.log('showed');
        }
        instance.onclose = function(){
            console.log('closed');
        }
    });

    messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function() {
         console.log('Notification permission granted.');
        messaging.getToken()
        .then(function(currentToken) {
            if (currentToken) {
                console.log(currentToken);
            } else {
                // Show permission request.
                console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                // Show permission UI.
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
        });

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
    });

    messaging.onTokenRefresh(function() {
        messaging.getToken()
        .then(function(refreshedToken) {
          console.log('Token refreshed.',refreshedToken);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct token? Or are you using the same token where you already received `NotRegistered` for?

Comment: Yes i am using the same the token (during deny and allow process firebase wont generate new token).
messaging.getToken() - gives older one only...

Comment: Then the second `NotRegistered` error is WAI. "*messaging.getToken() - gives older one only*" -- this should be the primary focus of your question, since I think this could an unexpected behavior.

Comment: Okay all i wanted once i deny and allow in browser then i want to send some notification to that token.  is that possible really ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration - 
Unregistration and re-registration may each take up to five minutes to propagate. During this time messages may be rejected due to the unregistered state, and messages may go to the wrong user.

---- but even after several hours also didnt work...

Answer (score 0):

I sent an email to google support and i got a reply

> From google support: I was able to replicate this on my end using the FCM JS quickstart sample, and found that it only affects SDK versions 4.10.0+. I've brought this bug to the attention of our engineers and we are now working on a fix. I can't share specific timelines on when it will be released in production, but in the meantime, I suggest using a lower version of the SDK (e.g. 4.9.0) as a workaround.
>
> Keep an eye out on the release notes or feel free to check back with
> me for any further updates on the fix.

So they have this issue in above firebase 4.10.0+